# how to retain the animated position in opengl es 2.0

Tags: animation, matrix, opengl-es

I am doing frame based animation for 300 frames in opengl es 2.0

I want a rectangle to translate by +200 pixels in X axis and also scaled up by double (2 units) in the first 100 frames.
For example, the initial value  (frame 0) of the rectangle's centre point is at 100 pixels (i.e. rectCenterX = 100) on the screen;
At 100th frame, rectCenterX = 300 (100 + 200) pixels. Also the rect size is doubled the original size.

Then, the animated rectangle has to stay there for the next 100 frames (without any animation). i.e. the rectCenterX = 300 pixels for frames 101 to 200.
At 101st frame, rectCenterX = 300 pixels. the rect size is double the original size.
At 200th frame, rectCenterX = 300 pixels. the rect size is double the original size.

Then, I want the same animated rectangle to translate by +200 pixels in X axis and also scaled down by half (0.5 units) in the last 100 frames.
At 300th frame, rectCenterX = 500 pixels.the rect size is again as the original size.

I am using simple linear interpolation to calculate the delta-animation value for each frame.

In short,

```
Animation-Type  Animation-Value  Start-Frame  End-Frame
1.Translate         +200            0           100
2.Scale             +2              0           100
3.Translate         +200            201         300
4.Scale             +0.5            201         300
```

Pseudo code:
The below drawFrame() is executed for 300 times (300 frames) in a loop.

```
float RectMVMatrix[4][4] = {1, 0, 0, 0,
                            0, 1, 0, 0,
                            0, 0, 1, 0,
                            0, 0, 0, 1
                           };   // identity matrix
int totalframes = 300;
float translate-delta;  // interpolated translation value for each frame
float scale-delta;  // interpolated scale value for each frame

// The usual code for draw is:
void drawFrame(int iCurrentFrame)
{
 // mySetIdentity(RectMVMatrix); // comment this line to retain the animated position.
  mytranslate(RectMVMatrix, translate-delta, X_AXIS); // to translate the mv matrix in x axis by translate-delta value
  myscale(RectMVMatrix, scale-delta); // to scale the mv matrix  by scale-delta value
  ... // opengl calls 
  glDrawArrays(...);
  eglswapbuffers(...);
}
```

The above code will work fine for first 100 frames. in order to retain the animated rectangle during the frames 101 to 200, i removed the "mySetIdentity(RectMVMatrix);" in the above drawFrame().

Now on entering the drawFrame() for the 2nd frame, the RectMVMatrix will have the animated value of first frame

e.g. RectMVMatrix[4][4] = { 1.01, 0, 0, 2,
                            0,    1, 0, 0,
                            0,    0, 1, 0,
                            0,    0, 0, 1
                           };// 2 pixels translation and 1.01 units scaling after first frame
This RectMVMatrix is used for mytranslate() in 2nd frame. The translate function will affect the value of "RectMVMatrix[0][0]". Thus translation affects the scaling values also.

Eventually output is getting wrong.

How to retain the animated position without affecting the current ModelView matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Although a direct answer would be to save the matrix you will need later I need to propose a different system as yours is extremely unclean and even if you make it for this animation you might have problems maintaining this code, adding animations or changing it.

To have an object animatable in terms of position, scale, rotations or even whole matrix I suggest you to create each of those parameters in the object itself (on the CPU) then on each and every frame set the matrix to identity and then recreate it from the parameters the object owns.

So for instance an object would have a vector called position which is animatable. What you need is hold 3 position parameters as in `positionCurrent`, `positionStart`, `positionEnd`. Now on the object you should call something like `animateWithFrameCount` As this method is called you need to set:

```
positionStart = positionCurrent;
positionEnd = input;
currentFrame = 0;
frameCount = inputFrameCount;
```

Then implement a method such as `onFrame` where

```
currentFrame++;
positionCurrent = positionStart + (positionEnd-positionStart)*(currentFrame/frameCount); //linear interpolation
if(currentFrame >= frameCount) {
    currentFrame = 0;
    frameCount = 0;
    positionStart = currentPosition = positionEnd;
}
```

If you implement this system for all animatable parameters you want all you now need is get the model matrix which again should be a models method (pseudocode):

```
Matrix16f getModelMatrix {
   Matrix16f toReturn = Matrix16f.identity();
   toReturn.translate(currentPosition);
   toReturn.scale(currentScale);
   ...
   return toReturn;
}
```

So now your `drawFrame` becomes quite straight forward. On all your models you need to call `onFrame`, set the matrix to identity (or maybe some other matrix), multiply the current matrix with the one received from the model and then just draw the thing. No issues with retaining, no conditional statements in your main code...